# Flutter cannot switch channel

Tags: git, flutter, git-pull, flutter-channel

My flutter works fine with stable channel, but when switching to another channel it ended up with `find: invalid mode '+100'`

Everytime I run this command :

```
> flutter channel master
> flutter doctor
```

is always end up downloading a git and the error with message :

```
find: invalid mode ‘+100’
```

I have run :

```
git clean -xfd
git pull
flutter doctor
```

but always end up with same error message, here's the screenshot:

[image: screenshot]

Any idea what's wrong with my flutter ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I just discovered that this problem is related to `find`, not flutter. I had a non-standard version of `find` installed, and after removing its directory from my `PATH`, updating flutter worked fine.

(I'm on macOS, and my problematic `find` came from the gnutls package, provided by MacPorts, and was located inside `/opt/local/libexec/gnutls`.)

Comment: yes you right, this problem related with findutils from brew, after uninstalling findutils problem solved.